# Why is my React frontend's reverse proxy API calls returning 404 not found from Laravel backend on subdomain?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, nginx, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am using a droplet on Digital Ocean for my database. Here are the two config files for each /etc/nginx/sites-available/ :

domain.com config file:

```
server {

    root /var/www/domain.com/build;

    index index.html;

    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
        }

}

server {
    if ($host = domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name www.domain.com domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

and here is the sub.domain.com config file:

```
server {

    root /var/www/sub.domain.com/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name sub.domain.com sub.domain.com;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';

}

server {
    if ($host = sub.domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



    server_name sub.domain.com www.sub.domain.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 8000;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
}
```

Here is my App.jsx:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import Education from "./components/Education";
import Employment from "./components/Employment";
import Project from "./components/Project";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState(null);
    const [education, setEducation] = useState(null);
    const [employments, setEmployments] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async (api, setter) => {
            try {
                const url = `/api/${api}`;
                const res = await fetch(url);
                const json = await res.json();
                setter(json);
                console.log(json);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        };
        fetchData("employments", setEmployments);
        fetchData("education", setEducation);
        fetchData("projects", setProjects);
    }, []);

    //Resume section
    //Employment data
    let employmentArray = [];
    if (projects) {
        for (let i = 0; i < employments.length; i++) {
            employmentArray.push(<Employment data={employments[i]} />);
        }
    }

    //Education data
    let educationArray = [];
    if (education) {
        for (let i = 0; i < education.length; i++) {
            educationArray.push(<Education data={education[i]} />);
        }
    }

    //Project data
    let projectArray = [];
    if (projects) {
        for (let i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
            projectArray.push(<Project data={projects[i]} />);
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <section id="home" className="home-container">
                <Home />
            </section>
            <hr id="division" />
            <section id="about" className="about-container">
                <About />
            </section>
            <hr id="division" />
            <section id="resume" className="resume-container">
                <h2 className="section-heading">Resume</h2>
                <div className="experience-container">
                    <h3 className="experience-type">Employment</h3>
                    {employmentArray}
                </div>
                <div className="experience-container">
                    <h3 className="experience-type">Education</h3>
                    {educationArray}
                </div>
            </section>
            <hr id="division" />
            <section id="projects" className="projects-container">
                <h2 className="section-heading">Projects</h2>
                <div className="projects-content-container">{projectArray}</div>
            </section>
            <Footer />
        </>
    );
}

export default App;
```

It appears from the domain.com it isn't able to find any of the data from projects, employments, and education. Meanwhile on the sub.domain.com it is working fine and I've tried using postman on the `sub.domain.com/api/projects` and it shows the data. The backend seems to be fine. I haven't a clue as to where to look anymore.